# Ubuntu LiveUSB rebooting at desktop

Tags: boot, live-usb

I'm having a very odd issue when installing Ubuntu on my new system: once the LiveUSB hits the desktop, the computer abruptly reboots. Normally I'd consult the logs to see what happened, but it seems LiveUSB don't like to log things.

I've tried quite a few versions of Ubuntu (19.04, 18.04.3, 18.04.2, 19.10 daily for newest possible Kernel, Xubuntu 18.04.3 and Ubuntu Server 18.04 for a GUI less test). I've also tried quite a few options in the motherboards config, but to no avail.

Hardware is the following:
Annoyingly 
- Ryzen 3700X
- Gigabyte X570 I Aorus Pro Wifi (with latest microcode to fix rdrand issue)
- RX Vega 56 Graphics

Windows does work on this system, so it's *probably* not hardware failure.

No CPU/RAM/GPU overclocks; XMP for RAM is enabled, but I have tested with XMP disabled and it does not appear to make a difference.

Are there any ideas for what's going on here? And if not, is it possible to get log files from a Live USB?

Comment: re:"with latest microcode to fix rdrand issue"... are you referring to the BIOS, or something else? If not, do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and check the manufacturer's web site for BIOS updates. Also know that some Ryzen processors had a recall due to Linux problems, so you may wish to check if yours is one of the effected ones.

Comment: Strictly speaking, I'm referring to the microcode component of the bios where the rdrand fix was, but yes I am running the latest version of the bios. To the best of my knowledge, the Ryzen processor recall was on the first-gen processors - my 3700X is third gen, and should be fine.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C memory` and `free -h`. Do you have your CPU or RAM overclocked? Go to https://www.memtest86.com/, and download/run the free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory.

Comment: I take it I'm missing something in those instructions; the machine crash/reboots before I can do anything, so I'm not clear how I can run any commands (otherwise I'd have been looking in the logs to see what's going on). In case it's something in the GUI that's causing the crash I'll try using Ubuntu Server tomorrow, because I think that should get me to a command prompt if nothing else. I've added more info to the post about overclocks etc (i.e. none in place at the moment) - will try to get Memtest done tomorrow as well, but obviously that will take some time.

Comment: If you boot to the Live USB, you may see an icon at early boot time that looks like a little man standing next to a keyboard, hit the SHIFT/SPACE/RETURN key (I don't remember which), then a new menu appears at the bottom of the screen, hit F6 to select the last item, and enable "nomodeset", and see if it boots fully then. You can also try booting into recovery mode from the GRUB screen, hit Advanced Options, select Recover Mode, and then Root Access, which should get you to a # prompt. Type "startx" (or maybe "exit", or control-D... I don't remember which) to bring up the GUI. Report back.

Comment: See https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/X570-AORUS-PRO-WIFI-rev-10/support#support-dl-bios for a new BIOS version F4j just released on 8/2/2019.

Comment: As previously stated, I am on the latest bios version, which is indeed F4j. Memtestx86 has given me 1 clean pass so far. Nomodeset has been tried and no effect. The Ubuntu LiveUSB lacks an Advanced Options menu, so there is no Recover Mode to try. Also for reference, using a UEFI boot is the quickest way to get to Grub on an Ubuntu LiveUSB - you don't have to worry about the 'little man' in this case. I suppose it's also worth me noting that I've been using the LiveUSB self-check to verify the disk is working correctly, and that's been fine too.

Comment: I think my next step will be to install Ubuntu onto a USB (by booting the Ubuntu install media in a VM with USB pass-through), boot that, and then see if I can extract any logs from it.

Comment: The Live USB doesn't have persistent storage, so you won't be able to recover any logs after the crash. Are you able to get to the GRUB menu on your main HDD? If so, see if there's a Advanced Options/Recovery Mode/etc there.

Comment: I can't install, so obviously there is no Ubuntu/GRUB on my main disks. Also please note that what my plan is not to create a LiveUSB, but to create a bootable install of Ubuntu on a USB, which will have persistent storage and logs.

Comment: Well... I obviously haven't been paying close enough attention. Sorry about that. Were you ever able to finish memtest? In your hardware configuration, is there anything that you can strip back to make a minimal configuration that maybe Ubuntu Install/Live would like better? USB devices, extra HDD's, memory?

Comment: I've (finally) found that booting with the kernel option acpi=off lets me boot, so this is obviously an acpi bug somewhere. Updating the question with an answer in progress. To answer your question (although it's less important now) Memtest passed all tests. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of testing, I found that booting with the kernel option `acpi=off` allows the boot to occur. Obviously this points to other issues, but for posterity, if anyone else is having a similar issue with a similar setup, this might be the way to go for now.

EDIT: Updating this for the definitive answer - it turned out that the processor was faulty. After some time, these faults rendered Windows inoperable as well, and RMA'ing the processor got Ubuntu to boot on the machine. So if you have a machine where Windows boots and Linux doesn't, it could well be defective hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Current 19.10 live image logs on the live support *by default* (it even creates the log partition if it's missing), for the better and for the worse. I'm personally against this, **being read-only should be the default behaviour**. Moreover, even with the default read-only policy that's in force on previous live systems, you can create and format an ext4 volume, and label it `casper-rw`, then boot the live system and pass the `persistent` parameter on the kernel command line, which should make the live system have persistent logging.