# Booting or installing from Live USB fails

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 19.04 on my new PC running on Windows 10 now. No matter which option from grub I pick, I'm stuck on loading screen with 5 dots. I've manually edited grub options and removed `quiet splash` so I can see what is going on. The result of selecting `Try without installation` is on [the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SP5gc.jpg). I've tried running both with and without`nomodeset` option set - no effect. Output on screen is with that option in grub options.

Pendrive was made on other Windows 10 machine using Rufus. I've used GPT partition.

**PC specs:**

- Ryzen 3700x
- Gigabyte Aorus x570 elite
- Gigabyte Windoforce RTX 2070 super
- Corsair MP510 PCIe M.2 960 GB

There was also some info in output like `could not mount read-write trying read-only`.

How can I fix it?  I've installed ubuntu on some other PCs and it was fine, it's first time I'm facing such problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known `RdRand` issue with latest AMD Ryzen 3700x, 3900x etc processors, as described in these AskUbuntu, and Phoronix threads [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161799/installation-failure-on-amd-ryzen-3900x-and-gigabyte-auros-master-x570-motherboa/1161859#1161859), [2](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ryzen-3K-RdRand-Systemd-Maybe), and [3](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=AMD-Releases-Linux-Zen2-Fix).

So until you get the BIOS fix from your motherboard vendor, you can either install and use Ubuntu 18.04, or install 18.04 first and then upgrade to 19.04.

In addition to Ryzen's RdRand issue, Gigabyte X570 motherboards could run into another issue of setting kernel option `acpi=off`, as detailed in this Askubuntu thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165886/ubuntu-liveusb-rebooting-at-desktop/1166169#1166169).

Comment: Updated bios to the newest one and 19.04 installed flawlessly. Thanks a lot!